# Build subscription alerts for service changes

Tags: uddi

I am using Biztalk UDDI V3 (stand-alone install) on a windows 2008. I have configured all services (web, database and subscription):

- I successfully published a couple of services
- I successfully accessed and retrieved service information from my .net console application.

My issue at this point is with the subscription service. I tried to subscribe to one of the published services only to find out that I need to create my own listener.

I followed the steps listed [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/soa-capabilities-in-biztalk-uddi). Please take a look at the section entitled "Building subscription alerts for service changes". I am confused as to what the WCF service I create is supposed to look like. The instructions state the following:

***Now we create a new WCF Service project and reference this existing service library. After making sure the .svc file points to our referenced library object, and adding a valid endpoint configuration file, view our service in the web browser to ensure that it's up and running**.*

I find this section confusing. Not sure what public methods would the WCF service expose(if any at all) or how to expose the functionality within the service library that I just referenced from within my WCF project.

Of course, if you know of a different way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish, that also would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. I actually just wrote a complete port for Apache jUDDI's client library using .NET C#. One of the use cases is actually what you are attempting to do. Here's the rough approach used.

- Generate the code from wsdl (using wsdl.exe, because svcutil doesn't like the UDDI wsdls)
- Alter the interface code to have WCF bindings for the Subscription Listener class
- Create an implementation of the subscription listener and handle the callbacks
- Fire up the implementation using WCF's embedded service
- Register your sub listener endpoint with UDDI (using the correct annotations per the spec)
- Setup the subscription using your sub listener's binding template
- Wait for callbacks

Here's the code
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-client.net/

Example
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-client.net/juddi-client.net-sample/org.apache.juddi.client.samples/SubscriptionCallbackExample.cs

There's also a Java version that does the exact same thing.